# External display sometimes briefly turns on but stays black

Tags: display, sleep-wake, mac-pro

I have a 2019 Mac Pro (the new cheese grater) connected to an external display via Thunderbolt 3. When I put it to sleep though, sometimes the display will turn on and display all-black for a few seconds (before going to the "No signal" state and eventually turning off). This happens even after:

- Disconnecting all other plugged-in devices
- Disabling "Wake for network access"
- Disabling Power Nap
- Disabling "Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer"

It's quite annoying when my display comes on at night after putting my computer to sleep. What other settings might I have missed/suggestions I should try to ensure my display doesn't come on?

Comment: Just a simple solution: turn off the monitor at night.

Comment: Heh that could work … although the power button is in a somewhat hard-to-reach place with my current setup so that's rather tricky in practice :)